# Round Date up or down using Moment

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am using Moment to compare two datetime values.  Specifically using Moment.isSameOrBefore.  My two date values are off by milliseconds.

I would like these two values to evaluate as the same:

```js
var date1 = '2019-07-09T15:30:05.8670088'
var date2 = '2019-07-09T15:30:06.3400766'
if (moment(date1).isSameOrBefore(date2, 'second')) {
    //do something
}
```

Is there a way to round, so the datetime values equal so evaluation is true?  Or another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It evaluates as `true`:

```js
var date1 = '2019-07-09T15:30:05.8670088'
var date2 = '2019-07-09T15:30:06.3400766'
var test = moment(date1).isSameOrBefore(date2, 'second');
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/moment"></script>
```